# How does Node.js behave against a low latency mobile network?

Tags: node.js

I want to develop a mobile app that reads and occasionally writes tiny chunks of text and images of no more than 1KB. I was thinking to use node.js for this (I think fits perfectly), but I heard that node.js uses one single thread for all request in an async model. It's ok, but what if a mobile through a very low latency network is reading byte by byte (I mean very slowly) one of that chunks of text? Does this mean that if the mobile needs 10 seconds after completing the read, the rest of the connections has to wait 10 seconds before node.js replies them? I really hope that no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No — incoming streams are evented.  The events will be handled by the main thread as they come in.  Your JavaScript code is executed only in this main thread, but I/O is handled outside that thread and raises events that trigger your callbacks in the main thread.